# Reduction from 2-SAT to 2-XOR-SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

*2-SAT is unsatisfiable iff it contains unsatisfiable XOR-2-SAT*.

So, first, we just need to combine **every** clause that contains share same variables (both of them). Then, all of those which remain uncombined are "uninteresting" (don't affect satisfiability).

Example:

$\Phi = (x \lor y) \land (\overline x \lor \overline y) \land (x \lor \overline z)\land(\overline x \lor z)\land (\overline y \lor z)\land (y \lor \overline z)\land (z \lor t)$

Now I can replace this formula by equisatisfiable (under log-space reduction):

$\Phi' = (x \oplus y)\land(x \oplus \overline z)\land(y \oplus \overline z)$

As you can see, clause $(z\lor t)$ was removed as "uninteresting".

Ah, well, I need to see if there are cycles in implication graph. So, finding a cycle in directed graph that contains two given vertices is $\mathsf{NL}$-complete problem, right?

Comment: What is the equality graph of a 2-SAT instance? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, if two literals are equal, then they are connected to each other in undirected equality graph. In my example there are edges $(x, \ \overline y), (x,\ z), (y,\ z)$.

Comment: That means you get an equality graph from _an assignment_, not from a 2-SAT instance. ​ Accordingly, what is your reduction from 2-SAT to USTCONN? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, but you can't put $x = y$. Otherwise one of two clauses will be unsatisfied. If you solve it with implication graph, you can solve it in $\mathcal{O}(\log^2 n)$ memory due to Savitch's theorem. But equality graph is undirected and I think it should imply that it's possible to solve 2-sat $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ memory.

Comment: How do you determine when you can put ​ x = y ? ​ ​ ​ (If your answer involves solving 2-SAT instances, then your "reduction" doesn't help.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer, there are 4 cases: $(x \lor y) \land (x \lor \overline y) = x$, $(x \lor y) \land (\overline x \lor y) = y$, $(x \lor y) \land (\overline x \lor \overline y) = (x = \overline y)$, $(x \lor \overline y) \land (\overline x \lor y) = (x = y)$. It can be easily checked if you will make truth tables for these formulas.

Comment: What about cases beyond those 4? ​ ​ ​ (For example, ​ x or y ​ where no other clause uses both of those variables.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60370/discussion-between-rus9384-and-ricky-demer).

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn't work since you can't always pair clauses as in your example.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability), 2SAT is NL-complete. In particular, this means that it is not in logspace unless L=NL, which is considered unlikely.

Comment: I said first **pair** of clauses. $(x \lor y) \land (\overline x \lor \overline y)$ implies $x = \overline y$.

Comment: I know that such clauses can be anywhere in the formula. All you need in this case is to apply search each time you take a clause. Runtime will be quadratic, such kind of space-time tradeoff.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus  Do you mean it is not in L unless L=NL? I don't see the relation between LSPACE and NL-completeness.

Comment: L stands for logspace.